# Browser won't let the iframe do the redirect?

Tags: google-chrome, iframe

Google Chrome 23 and Firefox 18 is driving me nut.
I have a page, in which i have an iframe.
When a button click, I want the iframe to open `http://images.google.com`

The problem is the iframe will try to visit http://images.google.com, but as soon as it get a redirect instruction (which http://images.google.com is issueing), it halt and the page won't be rendered. Why is that? Any solution?

Here is a snippet demonstrate that issue:

```
<iframe id="panel" style="height: 800px; width: 100%" sandbox="allow-scripts" src="http://images.google.com">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Are you injecting the iframe into `http://images.google.com` page? The page is served with a `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` header.

Comment: That's being say there is no way to include images.google.com as an iframe into my page because it's only accepting SAMEORIGIN inclusion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a browser security issue, known as [Click-jacking prevention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking), part of which is to check for a HTTP response header, [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options). This header can take the values `DENY`, `SAMEORIGIN`, or `ALLOW-FROM` origin, which will prevent any framing, prevent framing by external sites, or allow framing only by the specified site, respectively.

Simply put, when this http header is there, it prevents the site from rendering in a `<frame>` or an `<iframe>`. Since 2009 this http header is implemented in most browsers including IE8+, Safari, Firefox, Chrome, and Opera.

Here are the headers from `images.google.com`, `SAMEORIGIN` means that the address could only be rendered inside an iframe when it is being surfed through `google.com`

[image]

Comment: that screenshot. good old times.