# Redirect iFrame from Node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe

I have a button that when pressed, opens a new window in which I have an iframe, that iframe's src attribute is the URL to my Node server endpoint.

That endpoint sends back a res.redirect('STRIPE_URL');

But the iframe is not redirecting to the Stripe URL.

When I open the new window directly to the endpoint URL, it works perfectly. But I lose the window.opener reference, that's why I'm using the iframe.

How can I make it work?

Comment: have you used developer tools to confirm that your iframe is receiving a proper redirect? e.g. 302 or 302 response with a Location header? 
Does the console show any errors?

Comment: I know it's getting it, because the browser network logs show the STRIPE_URL as a successful GET. However, nothing is shown

Comment: Why is you you need the iframe? You should just be able to include checkout.js in your page and use Stripe's API from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason in another thread, just I didn't know it was related to the browser. Read below, in case you are having the same issue:

[It is a browser security issue, known as Click-jacking prevention...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504516/browser-wont-let-the-iframe-do-the-redirect)