# Cross domain form submission inconsistent

Tags: php, html, cross-domain, form-submit

I've got two domains A and B.

A hosts a form `A/inquire` that submits a post request to `B/form-submission`
B accepts a POST request at `B/form-submission` and redirects to `A/thankyou`

One tricky thing here is that A hosts the form from within an `<iframe>` so when the user submits the form the iframe bounces to B then back to A.

About 10-20% of users experience an issue where submitting the form results in the iframe not getting redirect to `A/thankyou`, but the form data always gets saved so `B/form-submission`'s script must be finishing.

B/form-submission (PHP):

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');

... process form and insert data into db - works 100% of the time ...

header("Location: A/thankyou");
exit();
```

Of course, I am unable to reproduce this myself...

Is there a way to improve the reliability of this? It doesn't appear to be related to my form processing because the last thing that happens before the redirect is a database insertion that always goes through.

Comment: May be this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504516/browser-wont-let-the-iframe-do-the-redirect

Comment: Try defining `X-Frame-Options` header in all the pages that are going to be loaded in the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to commenters Gabriel and Taron.

[Ruby on rails 4 app does not work in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561066/ruby-on-rails-4-app-does-not-work-in-iframe)

The setting that breaks iFrames on remote sites is X-Frame-Options. By default, this is set to SAMEORIGIN, which prevents the content from being loading cross domain:

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
    'X-Frame-Options' => 'SAMEORIGIN'
}
```

Adding this fixed my problem