# iframe not resolving the proxy url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hybrid-mobile-app

In my React JS application, I am gettin a url from the backend which is a proxy url. If i type it in a new window, it'll resolve into the actual url and i see the content. But, when i try to render it in an iframe for the **hybrid application**, I am getting a blank page. There are no calls registered in the network.

eg:

```
http://www.example.com // proxy url
https://www.resolved-url.com // resolved url

<iframe
 id='example'
 title='this is an example iframe'
 src={proxyURL}
 frameBorder='none'
 height='1500'
 width='100%'></iframe>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Browser won't let the iframe do the redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504516/browser-wont-let-the-iframe-do-the-redirect)

Comment: @PeterKrebs, unfortunately no. I have to render it in an iframe, since it's a hybrid app.

Comment: The answers say it is a security feature of browsers to not do the redirect (click-jacking prevention). Search StackOverflow for other answers regarding iframe redirect issues. It is not a solution to your problem - I am saying what you are trying will not work. You must link to the target URL yourself without using a proxy domain.